# No elements were found with the selector: ".highlight"

Tags: jslint

I appreciate jslint telling me about my bad programming practices.
How can I get rid of a warning message I get when I issue this command:

```
$('.highlight').removeClass();
```

when there are no elements with class="highlight".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

> $('.highlight').each(function(){
>   $(this).removeClass(); });

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    $('.highlight').removeClass();
} catch (Exception) {
    // swallow. :)
}
```